# (Batch) Limit the useable windows version to be NT 6.1+

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I found this code in the RiiConnect24Patcher batch script wondering if I just put it at the start and if it's not windows 7+ It will run perfectly

```
if not exist "%MainFolder%" md "%MainFolder%"
if not exist "%TempStorage%" md "%TempStorage%"

:: Trying to prevent running from OS that is not Windows.
if not "%os%"=="Windows_NT" goto not_windows_nt
```

Thanks

Comment: spinkleboi, I have reformatted your question code, can you please confirm that yours looks exactly like that which is now showing?

Comment: Every version of Windows since Windows 2000 has had an `%OS%` value of `Windows_NT`. Like the comment says, that `if` statement basically just checks to see if you're running _some_ version of Windows that has come out in the last 20 years.

Comment: thing is there some code that can help me make it so windows 7 and over can use the app only?

Comment: Okay so you have not posted any code which is exhibiting an issue at all. You've posted some irrelevant code and are asking for something else instead. You could determine the OS version, _(using `reg.exe` / `WMIC.exe`)_, or cmd.exe version, _(using the `ver` command)_. There are loads of examples of doing so already within the pages of this site. What you're supposed to do is use the search facility to locate them, and adapt what you find, for your own purposes. Currently your question shows no attempt at research, or coding, and reads as an off topic code request. BTW, I expected a response!

Comment: Additionally, a properly developed 'app' should be written and designed to only install and/or work on compatible Operating Systems, so that functionality should technically already exist without the need for a basic batch file check. Also taking a look at the content of the batch file you're referring to, _(which contains 9807 lines much of it requiring improvement)_, there is already the following command `For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('ver') do set "windows_version=%%A"`, so the author should already have implemented some code using it, if it was necessary.

Comment: spinkleboi, I have removed your latest question edit content, as it should not include the solution within it. I returned your question to the content it was when my answer was submitted, as that is what I answered, but left your new/improved title in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example of my comment, open `RiiConnect24Patcher.bat` for editing, and in between the current line 3, `setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion`, and line 4, `cd /d "%~dp0"`, insert this:

```sh
"%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe" Query ^
 "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /V "CurrentVersion" ^
  2>NUL | "%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe" /I /R "\<6\.[123]\>" 1>NUL ^
   || GoTo :EOF
```

This uses the registry to get the Operating system version `6.1`, *(Server 2008 R2 / Home Server 2011 / Windows 7)*, version `6.2`, *(Server 2012 / Windows 8)*, or `6.3`, *(Server 2012 R2 / Windows 8.1 / Server 2016 / Windows 10 / Server 2019)*. If the version matches it will continue to the next line, (`cd /d "%~dp0"`). If it is older, the script will immediately close, (`GoTo :EOF`).

*The command is technically a single line, but I've split it over several for readability. If you want it as one very long line then just use this:*

```sh
"%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe" Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /V "CurrentVersion" 2>NUL | "%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe" /I /R "\<6\.[123]\>" 1>NUL || GoTo :EOF
```

Comment: You may need to check that Windows 10 and Server 19 are using version `6.3`, the versions of Windows 10 I've used did, although those may have been left overs from upgrades. I haven't checked the web for an authorative answer to this, but I do know that there are sources which incorrectly state `10.0`, when I know for a fact that the versions of Windows 10 I've used show `6.3`. You may need to use `"\<6\.[123]\ \<10\.0\>"`, to cater for those otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I'm just a dumb when it comes to things like these.